# ConnectyCube React Native VoIP push token issue

Tags: react-native, voip, connectycube

This is my normal, successful subscrition to apn or gcm channel

```
subcribeToPushNotification(deviceToken) {
    const params = {
      notification_channels: Platform.OS !== 'ios' ? 'apns' : 'gcm',
      device: {
        platform: Platform.OS,
        udid: DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()
      },
      push_token: {
        environment: __DEV__ ? 'development' : 'production',
        client_identification_sequence: deviceToken
      }
    }

    // JS SDK v2
    /*ConnectyCube.pushnotifications.subscriptions.create(params)
      .then(result => {console.log("RESULT: ", result)})
      .catch(error => {console.log("ERROR: ", error)});*/

    // JS SDK v1
    ConnectyCube.pushnotifications.subscriptions.create(
      params,
      (error, result) => {
        if (result)
          console.log("RESULT APNS: ", result)
        else
          console.log("ERROR VOIP", error)
      }
    );
  }
```

Now I need to use VOIP push notification, but when I try the following code:

```
subcribeToPushNotificationVoip(deviceToken) {
    const params = {
      notification_channels: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'apnsvoip' : 'gcm',
      device: {
        platform: Platform.OS,
        udid: DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()
      },
      push_token: {
        environment: __DEV__ ? 'development' : 'production',
        client_identification_sequence: deviceToken
      }
    }

    // JS SDK v2
    /*ConnectyCube.pushnotifications.subscriptions.create(params)
      .then(result => {console.log("RESULT: ", result)})
      .catch(error => {console.log("ERROR: ", error)});*/

    // JS SDK v1
    ConnectyCube.pushnotifications.subscriptions.create(
      params,
      (error, result) => {
        if (result)
          console.log("RESULT APNS: ", result)
        else
          console.log("ERROR VOIP LAST: ", error)
      }
    );
  }
```

`console.log` gives me this error :

```
 ERROR VOIP LAST:  {"code": 422, "detail": ["Invalid notification channel specified"], "message": {"errors": ["Invalid notification channel specified"]}, "status": "error"}
```

voip token example:    `4dd23c212d2a8865c4747ee278de0947d0de80445400f8f85cdb5a6f3923cb74`

I am using the Universal (Sandbox & Production & VoIP) SSL certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VoIP it should be

```
 notification_channel: "apns_voip"
```

- For VoIP pushes it requires to generate a separated push token when subscribe a user, please see how to get it https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-voip-push-notification#usage
- Then when token is retrieved, you need to subscribe to voip pushes by passing a ‘apns_voip’ channel in a subscription request
- Them when you want to send a voip push notification, also use ‘apns_voip’ channel when create an event

Comment: Would I be connected with a normal token so that I can connect to the apns_voip channel?

Do I need to generate a different token for voip?